# jquery works in chrome console not in page

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jquery function that removes the first class.
The problem is that it wont work when I use the script in the website, but it works fine when running the script inside the console(chrome)

Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.instagram-placeholder:first').hide();
});
```

http://akvesterberg.se/

Comment: is your website online give the link.if not post your markup.

Comment: @TusharGupta Yes its online, I updated the question.

Comment: There is most likely an error happening on the site which prevents the code form executing

Comment: Make sure jQuery is defined before your script.

Comment: @DJDavid98 Yes i though so, but i cant seem find any.

Comment: In your website which part you want to hide

Comment: Looks like divs are generated by script so try using window onload event instead of ready but a more robust workaround would be to create your own CSS rule

Comment: @Subhash I really want to hide the second image, since its a duplicate from the first(big) image.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can tell if your code isn't working, try streamlining your code files at the bottom of the page like this:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            $('.instagram-placeholder:first').remove();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the preferred method for loading scripts.  Also, you shouldn't really use inline js. The last part should be inside of your `script.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like you're loading your photos via ajax.

Basically, the document.ready() is called before the images are loaded, therefore no image can be hidden.

you should put your method call inside the success() function that's inside your script.js

Answer (score 0):

try this, this is done with counter, this is also work in your website

```
var counter=0
$('.instagram .instagram-placeholder').each(function(){
if(counter==0)
$(this).hide();
counter++;
});
```